# Получение части списка в Python

Tags: python

Имеется функция GetList(), она возвращает лист из 5 элементов.

```
A = GetList() # A = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Мне нужно получить значение 2 и 3 элементов, а остальные просто не нужны. На данный момент у меня есть 2 способа:

**1 Способ.**

```
x1,x2 = GetList()[2], GetList()[3] # Неудобно, и вызывает кучу лишних операций
```

**2 Способ.**

```
list = GetList()

x1,x2 = list[2], list[3]   # удобно, но очень долго писать и занимает 2 строки
```

Хотелось бы найти способ покороче и удобней.

UPD: Нашёл способ

```
x1,x2 = GetList()[2:3+1]  #  всё запишется верно
```

Но это не будет работать если мне например нужен 1ый и 5ый.

(Мне не нужны ответы типа GetList()[1:5+1:5])
Мне нужно узнать, можно ли получить значения определённых элементов листа.

Comment: а если переписать `GetList()`? Поправьте в этой функции или она нужна не только в этом случаем - добавьте флаг, чтобы вызов был например таким `GetList(2)`

Comment: Нет, мне нужен именно такой GetList()

Comment: ну, а так избавиться от двух присвоений вам не удасться

Comment: Вот я искал как раз распаковку)

Comment: @ВячеславСысоев ну распаковка например для первого и пятого не лучше чем `GetList()[1:5+1:5]) `. Придется писать что то вроде такого:              
         
`_, x1, _, _, _, x2, *_ = GetList()` и неудобно, и не параметризируешь. Захочется 2й и 12-й - переписывать код ручками...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Распаковка поможет

```
_, x1, x2, *_ = GetList()
```

или срезы

```
x1, x2 = GetList()[1:3]
```

Comment: работает только в `Python3`

Comment: @EugeneDennis частичная распаковка да, а срезы везде.